# Non singular degenerate conics in the projective plane

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, projective-space, finite-geometry

I was trying to count degenerate conics in the projective plane $\mathbb{P}^2(\mathbb{F}_q)$ and I discovered what ooks like a "paradox" (I know it's not but I can't solve it).

Given a point (let's say (0:0:1)) in $\mathbb{P}^2(\mathbb{F}_q)$ the space of singular conics passing throught it is nothing but the spaace of solutions of $ax_0+bx_0x_1+cx_1^2$ that has cardinality $q^2+q+1$.

On the other hand I thought that degenerate conics were of the form $L_1*L_2$ (the two lines can also be the same), there are q+1 lines through any point and so there should be $(q+1)^2=q^2+2q+1$ degenerate conics.

Why are the two numbers different? Are there q degenerate conics that are not singular?

EDIT: The first formula, that is indeed correct, comes from the fact that a point is said to be "smooth", and a point s that is not smooth is singular, if the conic equation vanishes only to order 1 at s, or equivalently, if at least one of the partial derivatives
of it is nonzero at s.

Let's now consider the generic conic equation $ax_0^2+bx_1^2+cx_2^2+dx_0x_1+ex_0x_2+fx_1x_2=0$, if we evaluate it at (0:0:1) we get $c=0$ and so the equation becomes $ax_0^2+bx_1^2+dx_0x_1+ex_0x_2+fx_1x_2=0$, we can now compute the partial derivative and find they are $P_0=2ax_0+dx_1+ex_2$, $P_1=2bx_1+dx_0+gx_2$, $P_2=ex_0+fx_1$, for the point to be singular we need all of these to be 0 if valuated at (0:0:1), now $P_0(0:0:1)=e\Rightarrow e=0$,  $P_1(0:0:1)=g\Rightarrow g=0$,  $P_2(0:0:1)=0$ and so the right equation we need to look for solutions to is indeed $ax_0^2+dx_0x_1+ex_1^2$.

My question is why doesn't the second way work too

Comment: Is a non-singular conic the same thing as a degenerate conic?

Comment: And you should probably notice that $L_1 \cdot L_2$ defines the same conic as $L_2 \cdot L_1$

Comment: They are probably the same in the projective space, they are not in an affine space (two parallel lines are not singular but their product is a degenerate conic). The definition of degeneracy is "it's not a parabola, an hyperbole, a circle or an ellipse" whilst the defintion of singular is "it has a singular point, i.e. a point where the order of vanishing is bigger than 1"

Also in this context the order is important so a differnt order of the factors means a 
different result

Comment: I mean the zero set of $ax_0+bx_ox_1+cx_1^2$, I have a proof this is the case, I can add it to the question if you like.

Regarding considering them disjoint I don't really have a reason but the fact that I'm trying to come up with the right number (because I know q^2+q+1 is the right number) and dividing by 2 doesn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To count the conics in $\mathrm{PG}(2,q)$, I will consider the set of homogeneous degree 2 polynomials
$$c_{0}X_{0}^{2} + c_{1}X_{1}^{2} + c_{2}X_{2}^{2}
+ c_{3}X_{0}X_{1} + c_{4}X_{0}X_{2} + c_{5}X_{1}X_{2}$$
there are $q^{6}-1$ such nonzero polynomials, and since we are associating a conic with the zero locus of such a polynomial, we get that there are $\frac{q^{6}-1}{q-1}$ conics in the plane (in the sense of their algebraic equation; it is possible that some of these equations define the same point set of $\mathrm{PG}(2,q)$).

If we want to count the number of *degenerate* conics, it is worth noticing that these come in **three** forms (I borrowed the example from Stanley Payne's extensive Topics In Finite Geometry, which sadly seems to no longer be available online):

1. a line (counted twice); e.g. $X_{0}^{2}$
2. a pair of distinct lines (contrary to what you state in the question body, order does not matter); e.g. $X_{0}X_{1}$
3. a single point (this is a possibility since, unlike $\mathbb{C}$, $\mathbb{F}_{q}$ is not algebraically closed; this case corresponds to a pair of conjugate lines in $\mathrm{PG}(2,q^{2})$); e.g. $X_{0}^{2}+aX_{0}X_{1}+bX_{1}^{2}$ with $a$ and $b$ chosen so this polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_{q}$.

There are $q^{2}+q+1$ degenerate conics of the first form, and ${q^{2}+q+1 \choose 2}$ of the second form.

The number of conics of the third form is given by $\frac{1}{2}(q^{2}+q+1)(q^{2}-q)$; I'm being a little hand-wavy here; there are of course only $q^{2}+q+1$ point sets of $\mathrm{PG}(2,q)$ of the third type but this counts the number of these degenerate conics considered over $\mathrm{PG}(2,q^{2})$. This count comes from noticing that each of the $q^{2}+q+1$ points of $\mathrm{PG}(2,q) \subset \mathrm{PG}(2,q^{2})$ is incident with $q^{2}+1$ lines, $q+1$ of which intersect $\mathrm{PG}(2,q)$ in $q$ other points, and the remaining $q^{2}-q$ containing no other points of $\mathrm{PG}(2,q)$; we cut this number in half because we are counting the conjugate pairs of lines. Of course, if you are defining a conic as a point set of $\mathrm{PG}(2,q)$ then there are only $q^{2}+q+1$ degenerate conics of this type.

Comment: Nice but I was talking about conics passing through a given point, not every conic in the space

Comment: Ok, this can be easily adapted to my case (just substituting q+1 to $q^2+q+1$ in the first two cases and 1 to $q^2+q+1$ in the last)

Indeed the problem was that I wasn't counting single points